Why the divided result is in 'int' instead of 'float'
I am very new to C#.
I have this code:
String CalcMethod;

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("enter P for plus, M for minus, T for times, lastly D for divide");
    CalcMethod = Console.ReadLine();

    if (CalcMethod == "P")
    {
        int num1, num2;
        Console.WriteLine("please enter number 1");
        num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("please enter number 2");
        num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
    }
    else if (CalcMethod == "M")
    {
        int num1, num2;
        Console.WriteLine("please enter number 1");
        num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("please enter number 2");
        num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
    }
    else if (CalcMethod == "T")
    {
        int num1, num2;
        Console.WriteLine("please enter number 1");
        num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("please enter number 2");
        num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
    }
    else if (CalcMethod == "D")
    {
        float Danswer;
        int num1, num2;
        Console.WriteLine("please enter number 1");

        num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("please enter number 2");
        num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Danswer = num1 / num2;
        Console.WriteLine(Danswer);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I AM ERROR HAHAHAHAHAHAARAAEAEAÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆaeaeææææææææææææææææææææææ");
    }
}

I tried setting Danswer to double but still didn't work
Sorry for bad English - it's not my main language.
I expected the result to be printed as a number with decimal points, like:
Input:
D
3
2

Output:
1.5

but that didn't work. How can I make the result be a float?
I am only talking about 'D' part

Using integers 3 divided by 2 gives the result as 1. So saving that as a float value it does not change. In order to get its 'true' (i.e decimal) value you must first convert at least one of the numbers to a float befor doing the division.

You need to cast one of the ints to float, e.g.: Danswer = (float)num1 / num2;. Otherwise you get integer division.

Thanks yall!  why don't you guys post these as answer?

^ because it has been answered before and we try not to create duplicates questions/answers as this would be counter productive to the aims of the site.

@JasonYeom: you should spend some time reading up on what constitutes a [mre].  In your case, such an example would like be less than 10 lines of code. Creating one often has 2 benefits: 1) in doing so, you will often solve your problem (by focusing the mind on a single issue and forgetting any wider problems) and 2) you will be more likely to get an answer - folks will see your issue quickly (compared to having to wade through a hundred lines of code)

ok thanks for letting me know
